# jQuery: assigning the enter key to submit an ajax form, what am I doing wrong here?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Le HTML:

```
<form action="/comment_replies/ajax_create/30?type=2" 
      id="new_comment_2_30" method="post" 
      onsubmit="new Ajax.Request('/comment_replies/ajax_create/30?type=2',
                                {asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true,
                                 parameters:Form.serialize(this)});
                return false;">

        <textarea class="tb_input_text_area" cols="40" 
                      id="comment_reply_body" name="comment_reply[body]"></textarea>

        <input class="action_button" id="comment_reply_submit" 
                   name="commit" type="submit" value="Comment">
    </form>
```

And my javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$j(function(){
    form_id = 'new_comment_2_30';

    $j(form_id + "textarea#comment_reply_body").focus();

    $j("#comment_reply_body").keypress(function(e){
        if(e.which == 13){
            e.preventDefault();

            $j(form_id).submit();
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

So, is .submit() not how you submit ajax forms? I know it works with non-ajax forms.
The goal is to make this from kinda like the comment boxes on facebook (just type, and hit enter when ready to submit)

NOTE: $j = jQuery.noConflict, ruby on rails 2.3.8 uses prototype as it's default js lib

Also, as I side question: the .focus() doesn't focus the textarea when the form loads o.o, is there anything special I need to do for a textarea to have focus?

Comment: As a side note: you could use jquery's [ajaxform plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) and you should only submit when <kbd>Shift</kbd> is not pressed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In jQuery, ID-selectors have to be prefixed by a sharp (`#`). Change your declaration to:

```
var form_id = '#new_comment_2_30';
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Rob W said, you are concatenating your selectors as:

```
form_id + "textarea#comment_reply_body"
```

you need space to have nested selector:

```
form_id + " textarea#comment_reply_body"
```